# Error when try to enable fingerprint validity vfs0050

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

When I try to enable fingerprint sensor on ubuntu 20.04 system shows:

```
No se pudo acceder al dispositivo <<Validity VFS0050>>
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

Screenshot after trying to enable fingerprint sensor:

[image: Ventana mostrada luego de intentar habilitar Sensor de Huella Digital / Screen show after try to enable fingerprint sensor validity vfs0050]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are the same bug reported but see this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1878285

I have the same issue with the same model of fingerprint reader device and it looks like it is a known issue upstream and fixed here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/commit/90ccf9a0af6df135be09cebb0eeb5906e49d92a6